# CRC checksum of ELF file

Tags: c, linux, security, elf, crc32

I need an opinion from somebody who has some experince with assuring file integrity.
I am trying to protect the integrity of my file with a crc checksum. My primary goal is to make harder bypassing a licence file check (which consist in disassembling the executable and removing a conditional jump).

I came up with the following idea:

```
unsigned long crc_stored = 4294967295;
char* text_begin = (char*)0xffffffffffffffff;
char* text_end = (char*)0xffffffffffffffff;

int main(){
    unsigned long crc = calc_checksum(text_begin, text_end);
    if (crc == crc_stored)
        //file is ok
}
```

I edit the `.data` section of the elf binary in the following way: `text_begin` and `text_end` will contain the begin and end address of the `.text` section, and `crc_stored` the crc checksum of the `.text` section.

I would like to know whether this is a proper way of doing this, or there are better methods?

Edit: Karoly Horvath has right. Let's say I use the crc check to decrypt some code. I would like to know which is the best way ro checksum protect the executable.
Olaf also has right. I can use a sha algorithm. The question is the same.

Edit2: please stop saying that any protection can bypassed. I know and I just want to make it harder. Please answer the question if you can.

Comment: Ok, so now the attacker has to remove not one, but two conditional jumps (`crc == crc_stored`)....

Comment: A CRC is not a signature/hash.

Comment: If you cannot control the environment where the executable is run, there is no way to stop determined hacker. No matter how many checksums, hashes or encryptions you put on top of it. Thus only question remains; how much time and money are you willing to spend to make his task a bit harder?

Comment: @user694733 It is up to me how much time I want to spend. I simply do not believe that not implementing any protection would be the proper solution.

Comment: You are basically asking: *"When is my protection good enough?"*. Problem is that we don't know how much better solution you need. We don't know how determined hacker you are trying to stop. You can make it harder, but there is no upper limit for it. I am not trying to be intentionally difficult; it's just that your question is currently impossible to answer.

Comment: @user694733, I am not asking "When is my protection good enough?". I am asking what is the proper/usual/most applied way to include a checksum in a binary.

Comment: @user694733, why is it impossible to answer? I proposed a solution. I you know a better one please describe it. But you just say that there is no proper protection.

Comment: If you feel that checksum is suitable, then no problem: This is the level of protection you are aiming for. I would ask you to be more specific with your question however: What is the problem with your current approach? If it works, then it's good enough.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Based on the upvotes it becomes I will accept it.

Comment: A simple checksum or CRC is good for detecting random errors caused by incomplete writes, transmission failures, etc.  To prevent nefarious hackers needs a stronger level.  Recommend a 512+ -bit [message authentication code](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Message_authentication_code).

Comment: It is ridiculous that anytime I ask something software protection related question, some people instead of helping just try to convince me that there is no perfect solution. This way I should not train myself, because I will surely die?

Answer (score 0):

Let me see. You have code that does this:

```
int main() {
  if (!license_ok()) { exit(1); }
  // do something useful
}
```

You are worried that someone will disassemble your code, and patch out the conditional jump, so you are proposing to change the code this way instead:

```
int main() {
  if (calc_checksum() != stored_crc) { exit(1); }
  if (!license_ok()) { exit(1); }
  // do something useful
}
```

I hope you see that this "solution" is not really a solution at all (if someone is capable of patching out one conditional jump, *surely* he is just as capable of patching out two such jumps).

You can find ideas for a more plausible / robust solution in [one](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B00RWTO4SG) of the [many](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/078214327X) [books](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0764574817) on the subject.

Comment: this was already pointed out by Karoly Horvath, therefore I edited the question, saying that I use the crc check as a password to decrypt some part of the code. This does not answer my question. The second book does not go in the details I need, the other one is 13 years old and focuses only on Windows. But I will check it.

Comment: @franz1 If your question is "how do I checksum my executable" (however pointless doing that is), the answer is: any way you like.

Comment: my question is: what is the standard way to do this.

Answer (score 0):

Do not stop the programme from running.
If the license is wrong at the start some strange behaviour is likely after 1 to 5 minutes,
causing segfaults, wrong calculations, whatever.
But in some indirect ways. Like a 2nd thread that modifies calculations or changes a random bit in the stack of another thread if the license is wrong.

Also get a Map of yourself at runtime by `/proc/self` and run a checksum on your `.text` sections at runtime.
That way you also can find some runtime modifications.

But the bitter truth is,
if it is runnable then it is just a question of how much effort the attacker needs to get a unlicensed copy running. It is not important to make it unrunnable. Just the effort of getting it cracked must be bigger than the effort.

Comment: So, instead of letting the user know the license is violated, make the user think your product is [a P.O.S](https://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=POS)?  That's not productive.  All you really need to do is make the license protection hard enough to defeat that there's no way the user could cleaim, "I didn't mean to do that!"  That way at least large companies can be held liable for deliberate license violation.  Because if no one even tries to violate your software license, that means no one wants your product.

Comment: A game i used to play (The Settlers 3) let the blacksmith produce pigs instead of iron if it detected a cracked version. 

Of course one can add a message that is activated a different (easy to spot) way. So a user knows that the software knows it got cracked.